# Наследование шаблона класса

Tags: c++, наследование, шаблоны-с++

### Что не так с конструктором базового шаблона?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <class T1>
class TypeSize {
public:
    TypeSize(T1 value) {
        this->value = value;
    }
    void DataTypeSize() {
        cout << "value size is " << sizeof(T1) << endl;
    }
private:
    T1 value;
};

template <class T1>
class TypeInfo : public TypeSize<T1> {
public:
    TypeInfo(T1 value) : TypeSize(value) {                 //<<<<<<< Ошибка!

    }
};


int main() {

    int a = 2;
    TypeInfo<int> c(a);
    c.DataTypeSize();

    return 0;
}
```

> Ошибка    C2512   TypeSize: нет подходящего конструктора по умолчанию Project1    e:\sources\l_151_classtemplateinheritance.cpp   39
>
> Ошибка    C2614   TypeInfo: недопустимая инициализация члена: "TypeSize" не является базовым классом или членом  Project1    e:\sources\l_151_classtemplateinheritance.cpp   39

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте написать

```
TypeInfo(T1 value) : TypeSize<T1>(value) {
```

(см. https://ideone.com/Mo8cir)

Comment: Спасибо ! Сработало. В источнике, откуда я это взял, у человека стоит Visual Studio 2015 и там все прекрасно компилируется..

Comment: @Григорий,  не может быть

Comment: @ARHovsepyan В VC++ 2017 компилируется, так что...

Comment: @Harry,  удивлен

Answer (score 2):

Имя `TypeSize` (без указания аргументов шаблона) является унаследованным членом шаблонного класса `TypeSize<T1>`. Это так называемое *инжектированное имя* класса. Т.е. его полное имя - `TypeSize<T1>::TypeSize` - это член базового класса `TypeSize<T1>`.

Если базовый класс является шаблоном и зависит от параметров вашего шаблона (как в вашем случае), то поиск *неквалифицированных* имен в таком базовом классе **не производится**. Эта тема тут уже не раз здесь всплывала

[Вызов функции_члена шаблонного базового класса из функции производного шаблонного класса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/918162/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3)

Именно по этой причине "простое" неквалифицированное имя `TypeSize` не видно из вашего конструктора.

Если бы ваш базовый класс не зависел от параметров вашего шаблона, то такой проблемы бы не было

```
template <class T1>
class TypeInfo : public TypeSize<int> {     // <- Нет зависимости от `T1`...
public:
    TypeInfo(T1 value) : TypeSize(value) {  // <- ... и нет ошибки
    }
};
```

Исправить ошибку в вашем случае вы можете либо так, как указано в ответе @Harry, т.е. отказавшись от ссылки на унаследованное инжектированное имя и указав вместо него имя самого базового класса. Или (просто ради лучшего понимания теории) можно таки упрямо настоять на своем и сослаться именно на унаследованное инжектированное имя класса через его *квалифицированное* имя

```
template <class T1>
class TypeInfo : public TypeSize<T1> {
public:
    TypeInfo(T1 value) : TypeSize<T1>::TypeSize(value) {  
    }
};
```

---

В Visual Studio код может компилироваться из-за того, что в режиме по умолчанию Visual Studio неправильно реализует двухфазный поиск неквалифицированных имен в шаблонах. Однако если вы включите режим боле строгого следования стандарту языка в Visual Studio (`/permissive-`), то этот код не будет компилироваться и в Visual Studio.

Comment: `: TypeSize<T1>::TypeSize(value)` можно сократить до `: TypeSize<T1>(value)`. Забавно, из-за инжектирования даже `: TypeSize<T1>::TypeSize::TypeSize::TypeSize(value)` компилируется.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Я привел этот пример именно для иллюстрации *теории*. Сократить нельзя, ибо теоретически это не одно и то же. `TypeSize<T1>` - это просто имя базового класса. А вот `TypeSize<T1>::TypeSize`, `TypeSize<T1>::TypeSize::TypeSize` и т.д. - это ссылки на член базового класса, на **инжектированное имя** класса внутри класса `TypeSize<T1>`. Здесь есть веская концептуальная разница.

Comment: Пардон, проглядел фразу *"ради лучшего понимания теории"*.