# Наследник-класс не видит переменную

Tags: c++

```
template <class T1>
class TypeSize
{
  public:
    TypeSize(T1 value)
    {
      this->value = value;
    }
    void DataTypeSize()
    {
      cout << "value =  " << sizeof(value) << endl;
    }
  protected:
     T1 value;
};

 template <class T1>
 class TypeInfo : public TypeSize <T1>
 {
   public:
   TypeInfo(T1 value) : TypeSize<T1>(value)
   {

   }
   void ShowTypeName()
   {
      cout << "Название типа " << typeid(value).name() << endl; // ошибка 'value' was not declared in this scope
   }
 };

int main()

{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    double a;
    TypeInfo<double> c(a);

    c.DataTypeSize();
    c.ShowTypeName();

    return 0;
}
```

Наследник не видит объявления переменной?

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте указать явно, где искать имя:

```
typeid(TypeSize<T1>::value)
```

(См. https://ideone.com/KqW2R3)

Теорию поиска имен, увы, пусть расскажут гуру в стандартах... Я в ней вечно сам путаюсь :(

Comment: Нужно указывать явно -- откуда переменная? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Вы должны указать член какого класса вам нужен, потому что имя члена является зависимым именем. от параметра шаблона. Это делается путем явного указания на данный обьект:

```
typeid(this->value)
```

Или путем явного указания имени типа, как сказано в ответе от `Harry`

Чтобы не повторяться в обьяснениях, можете прочитать [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/918162/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3)

Comment: Спс, пр-ки разобрался.