# Наследование от шаблонного класса

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, наследование

Рассмотрим вот такой код:

```
template<typename T> class A
{
public:
    T GetT()
    {
        return T{};
    }
};

template<typename U> class B : public A<U>
{
public:
    U GetU()
    {
        return GetT(); // Эта строка не компилируется
    }
};
```

Этот код не компилируется. GCC 8.1, в частности, выдаёт такую ошибку:

> error: there are no arguments to 'GetT' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'GetT' must be available [-fpermissive]
>
> (if you use '-fpermissive', G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)

Аналогичную ошибку выдаёт и Microsoft (правда, почему-то не всегда).
Чтобы функция `GetU` откомпилировалась, её надо переписать так:

```
template<typename U> class B : public A<U>
{
public:
    U GetU()
    {
        return A<U>::GetT(); // теперь всё хорошо
    }
};
```

Такое поведение мне не понятно. Ясно, что компиляторы отвергают первый вариант `GetU` не потому, что не могут найти `GetT`. GCC предлагает использовать ключ `-fpermissive', msc вообще компилирует без всяких сообщений мой исходный код, из которого я вырезал показанный минимальный пример. Тогда возникает вопрос: **зачем**? Не логичнее ли было бы сделать так, чтобы наследование от шаблонного класса вело себя так же, как наследование от обычного? Какую цель преследовали те, кто заложил в язык такое поведение?

Comment: или можно `this->GetT()` Похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/918162/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan Вот оно что. `GetT` может внезапно оказаться типом. Спасибо! Предлагаю закрыть вопрос как дубликат

Comment: Да, там какраз дан замечательный ответ. Хотя я бы оставил вопрос открытым из за разных заголовков